# The use of far-infrared ceramics for water purification?

Tags: water, purification, water-treatment, electromagnetic-radiation, ceramics

I am struggling to understand how exactly far infrared ceramic balls help purify the water. It is stated that active ceramic taormine balls help purify the water by forming a 2 micrometer wavelength electro-magnetic field (far infrared-red ray) along the water passageway.

> Water molecules have a natural oscillation frequency of 2 micrometers. As the water passes through the filter, the FIR field will help in breaking up the water molecules (which are usually clumped together) into smaller pieces. This will help in maintaining a healthy body metabolism rate.

> Far-infrared rays suppress the growth of excessive free radicals and shorten the cluster chain of water. The purified and activated water has smaller water clusters, which are more efficient at protecting cells from various stimulants.

Claims like these are made by companies. Is this feasible?

Comment: Claims about products associated with selling such products should not be generally believed until confirmed by independent sources not related to the selling profit. The last 2 paragraphs seems to me like tossing around scientific-like terms to overhelm ordinary people to believe there is big science behind.

Comment: I think this is a well-elaborated question that can be useful for the future reference. Probably it's self-evident for specialists, but for average consumer it might be not. Instead of criticizing the post, I would thoroughly express why and how these promotion materials are wrong so that the fraud becomes evident for everyone. The question got many triggered, so use the rage against the companies' shady practices, not a person's post who dared to question their legitimacy. This scam needs to be exposed, not hidden.

Comment: @andselisk Good point, but I wouldn't know where to start. These claims are so totally random ... :D

Comment: @Albert 1. Water has no oscillation frequency, 2µm or other. 2. ceramic balls at room temperature do not emit any more FIR radiation than any other substance. 3. water clusters (which exist!) break up and re-form randomly at a tremendous rate anyway. (so much for homeopathy). 4. FIR energies cannot make or inhibit radicals. Sorry. Who tries to sell this? https://www.osmiowater.co.uk/ Vitamin C shower filter, great. :D

Comment: This one gave me a good laugh, too: https://www.osmiowater.co.uk/water-filters/deuterium-depleted-water-ddw.html

Comment: Consider the gullibility factor. Some people even believe political campaign promises!

Comment: Suppose the balls would irradiate the water with infrared light, what would be their driving force doing so?  You can't generate energy *ex nihilo* (one reason there are (at least some) patent offices refusing grants on a *perpetuum mobile*).  And depending on your jurisdiction, treatment of water is regulated; the European (incl. UK) side of the pond actually a bit more than the US American, as Tom Scott once summarized for Coca-Cola's fail to market Dasani in Britain ([youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD79NZroV88)).